# Why is my console telling me that it's expecting `!` when I try to deploy my program to mainnet for the first time?

Tags: anchor, rust, mainnet

I'm trying to deploy my Solana program to mainnet using `anchor deploy --provider.cluster mainnet`. When I first ran this command I got an `insufficient funds` error and it told me that I needed around 1.6 SOL in the program account. Just to be safe I sent 1.9 SOL to the pubkey that was output when it gave me the error. After I funded the account I tried deploying again with the same command and I got the error: `Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0x1`. Then I tried to recover my funds so that I could deploy again. I recovered the keypair and then I tried running the same command again.

This time I got this in the console:

```
Deploying workspace: https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com
Upgrade authority: /Users/dylanmolina/.config/solana/id.json
Error: expected !
```

I know that this error usually means that there's some sort of syntax error in the command but I believe that it's correct: `anchor deploy --provider.cluster mainnet`

Is there something else that may be causing this? Should I have more SOL in my program balance(currently at ~3.99 SOL)? Is this a syntax error? Faulty program? Any help would be appreciated here, thanks!

#### For reference:

`anchor.toml`:

```
[features]
seeds = false
skip-lint = false
[programs.devnet]
artsolbackend = "8oMdunAFJKYeLDwHa2KrhyNGvbLqk4uB3iC6g4nifuCm"

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "/Users/dylanmolina/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"
```

`lib.rs`:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult; //ProgramResult

declare_id!("8oMdunAFJKYeLDwHa2KrhyNGvbLqk4uB3iC6g4nifuCm");

#[program]
pub mod artsolbackend {
    use super::*;

    pub fn submit_post(ctx: Context<SubmitPost>, title: String, description: String, artwork: String, cta: String) -> Result<()> {
        let post: &mut Account<Post> = &mut ctx.accounts.post;
        let creator: &Signer = &ctx.accounts.creator;

        if title.chars().count() > 50 {
            return Err(error!(ErrorCode::TitleTooLong));
        }

        if description.chars().count() > 280 {
            return Err(error!(ErrorCode::DescriptionTooLong));
        }

        if cta.chars().count() > 150 {
            return Err(error!(ErrorCode::CTATooLong));
        }

        post.creator = *creator.key;
        post.title = title;
        post.description = description;
        post.artwork = artwork;
        post.cta = cta;

        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn send_sol(ctx: Context<SendSol>, amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
        let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
            &ctx.accounts.from.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.to.key(),
            amount,
        );
        anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
            &ix,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
            ],
        )
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SendSol<'info> {
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    from: Signer<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    to: AccountInfo<'info>,
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SubmitPost<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = creator, space = Post::LEN)]
    pub post: Account<'info, Post>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Post {
    pub creator: Pubkey,
    pub title: String,
    pub description: String,
    pub artwork: String,
    pub points: i64,
    pub stars: u64,
    pub cta: String,
}

//Discriminator 
const DISCRIMINATOR_LENGTH: usize = 8;

//PubKey
const PUBLIC_KEY_LENGTH: usize = 32;

//String Prefix
const STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX: usize = 4;

//Title
const MAX_TITLE_LENGTH: usize = 50 * 4;

//Description
const MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH: usize = 280 * 4;

//Artwork
const MAX_ARTWORK_LENGTH: usize = 100 * 4;

//Points & Stars
const INT_SIZE: usize = 8;

//CTA
const MAX_CTA_LENGTH: usize = 150 * 4;

impl Post {
    const LEN: usize = DISCRIMINATOR_LENGTH 
    + PUBLIC_KEY_LENGTH  //Creator
    + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_TITLE_LENGTH //Title
    + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_DESCRIPTION_LENGTH //Description
    + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_ARTWORK_LENGTH //Artwork link
    + INT_SIZE //Points
    + INT_SIZE //Stars
    + STRING_LENGTH_PREFIX + MAX_CTA_LENGTH; //CTA
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("The provided title should be 50 characters maximum!")]
    TitleTooLong,

    #[msg("The provided description should be 280 characters maximum!")]
    DescriptionTooLong,

    #[msg("The provided artwork file should have a link that's 100 characters maximum!")]
    ArtworkTooLong,

    #[msg("The provided CTA link shouls be a maximum of 150 characters!")]
    CTATooLong,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to make some informed guesses here.

You have `cluster = "devnet"` in your `Anchor.toml`. I recommend setting it to mainnet while deploying to mainnet.

I also recommend setting the cluster to mainnet in the command line, as in `solana config set -u m`.

That will then save you the `--provider.cluster mainnet`, and you can just issue a plain `anchor deploy`.

The funds will be deducted from the wallet that's set as update authority, in your case `/Users/dylanmolina/.config/solana/id.json`. No need to transfer anything.

In my case it was 8 SOL, so be sure to have enough funds in your wallet.

When you later close the account (i.e. un-deploy your program), you will get your deposit back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it really moved me forward. Now I'm using solana program deploy instead of anchor deploy because I need to recover the funds to continue the deployment. However, after passing in all the args and using the correct flags(it seems), I'm getting this error: Initial deployments require a keypair be provided for the program id. Right now I'm just passing in the program id that I declared in lib.rs after the --program-id flag but I'm not sure if I need to use the entire keypair or how to even get it.

Comment: please post a new question instead of starting an unrelated conversation in the comments